# When I run my Docker :pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, sql-server, django, docker, pyodbc

I am on windows11 and I have created an API with django and venv. My API deploys a time series model.
For the database, I don't have a script to initialize the database, my database comes from an external DB with Microsoft SQL Manager, I am connected to this database using pyodbc! Here is the file with which I connect to the database:

```
import pyodbc
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def connect_to_database():
    db_server = os.environ.get('DB_SERVER')
    db_name = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
    db_user = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
    db_password = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
    db_encrypt = os.environ.get('DB_ENCRYPT')
    db_trusted_connection = os.environ.get('DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION')
    db_driver = 'SQL Server'

    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        DRIVER=db_driver,
        SERVER = db_server,
        DATABASE = db_name,
        ENCRYPT = db_encrypt,
        UID = db_user,
        PWD = db_password,
        Trusted_Connection = db_trusted_connection)

    return conn
```

Then I tried to create my docker image and here is my Dockerfile :

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Set environment variables
ENV SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY \
    DEBUG=$DEBUG \
    ALLOWED_HOSTS_1=$ALLOWED_HOSTS_1 \
    ALLOWED_HOSTS_2=$ALLOWED_HOSTS_2 \
    AGENCY_1=$AGENCY_1\
    DB_SERVER=$DB_SERVER \
    DB_NAME=$DB_NAME \
    DB_USER=$DB_USER \
    DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD \
    DB_ENCRYPT=$DB_ENCRYPT \
    DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION=$DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
# installation de unixodbc-dev
# Install SQL Server ODBC driver
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    gcc \
    gnupg2 \
    curl && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

# Copy odbcinst.ini into the container
COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install pyodbc
RUN pip install pyodbc

# Expose the port for the application
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the command to start the API
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And that is my odbcinst.ini :

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

While turning my container, I have this error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: The driver name should be "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" when the script is run in the container rather than "SQL Server" (which is the legacy Windows ODBC driver).

Comment: @DanGuzman First of all thank you for your answer,
I replaced db_driver = 'SQL Server with db_driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' but unfortunately I got this error pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1': file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: So if you open a CLI to your Docker container and run `ls -la /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql*` what is the result?

Comment: If you're going to overwrite the installed `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file with one of your own choosing then have you considered installing the matching version of the driver? e.g.: `ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17=17.7.2.1-1`